# Parse mongodb document into string variables

Tags: java, mongodb

I am a MongoDB beginner. I am trying to use it with java api. I have few documents inserted into mongodb and I am done with connecting to mongo instance using java.

My challenge is, I am getting one document as a result of mongodb query through java.

The result is one document in mongo which looks like:

`{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "528f13b5b55008f6487f7988"} , "NodeName" : "saurabhdeshpande" , "FirstName" : "saurabh" , "LastName" : "deshpande" }`

I want to take all these returned values into string variables like

`String nodename, String firstname, String lastname`

Please suggest - Hw do i go about this?

Code I tried is -

```
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("NodeName", name);

        cursor = coll.find(query);
        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println(cursor.next());
                DBObject tobj = cursor.next();
                details[0] = (String) tobj.get("NodeName");
                details[1] = (String) tobj.get("FirstName");
                details[2] = (String) tobj.get("LastName");

                System.out.println("in details ");
                for (int i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("in details " + details[i]);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        mongoClient.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: share your code what u tried ??

Comment: I removed the jdbc tag, as MongoDB doesn't use the JDBC api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two cursor.next() in the same iteration which could cause runtime exception.

```
DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("NodeName", name);

    cursor = coll.find(query);
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {

            //System.out.println(cursor.next());
            DBObject tobj = cursor.next();
            System.out.println(tobj);
            details[0] = (String) tobj.get("NodeName");
            details[1] = (String) tobj.get("FirstName");
            details[2] = (String) tobj.get("LastName");

            System.out.println("in details ");
            for (int i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("in details " + details[i]);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    mongoClient.close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your result will be a BasicDBObject(which is basically a Map) say `result`.

```
String nodename = (String)result.get("NodeName");
String firstname = (String)result.get("FirstName");
String lastname= (String)result.get("LastName");
```

Comment: Thanks Ajai.. I tried this previously but it shows `java.lang.RuntimeException: no more` as an error.

Comment: I meant could you edit your question to include the snippet you has tried?

Comment: please have a look now. Thanks!

Comment: //System.out.println(cursor.next());
Try this. You are doing two cursor.next within the same iteration, which could make you go outside the bounds.

Comment: hey.. it worked! getting values prinjted in details array. Thanks a ton!